# TeamCity dotCover code coverage doesn't cover some methods

Tags: unit-testing, async-await, teamcity, code-coverage, dotcover

I use dotCover on teamcity and run unit test, but found some methods not included in code coverage (not highlighted in green or red), like the following code.
Where I can change this code coverage?

```
           [Route("messages")]
26         [HttpGet]
27         [HandleException]
28         public async Task<GetMessagesResponse> GetMessagesAsync(string cultureCode)
29         {
30             var messages = await _messageApiProxy.GetMessagesAsync(cultureCode, _userContext.UserId);
31 
32             return new GetMessagesResponse
33             {
34                 Result = Succeeded,
35                 Messages = messages.Select(TransformToModelFrom).ToArray()
36             };
37         }
38 
39         [Route("messages/{messageId}/{status:int}")]
40         [HttpGet]
41         [HandleException]
42         public async Task<GetMessageDetailResponse> GetMessageAsync(string cultureCode, Guid messageId, int status)
43         {
44             var message = await _messageApiProxy.GetMessageAsync(cultureCode, _userContext.UserId, messageId, status);
45 
46             return new GetMessageDetailResponse
47             {
48                 Result = Succeeded,
49                 MessageInfo = TransformToModelFrom(message)
50             };
51         }
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible to provide an answer without additional investigation. Please send CoverageReport.xml and dotCover.snapshot to JetBrains support team: http://dotnettools-support.jetbrains.com/anonymous_requests/new TeamCity publishes these files as hidden build artifacts.

Comment: it is solved when upgrading the teamcity,

Comment: Which Update did fix it? We`re having the same Problem on 8.1 (build 29879)...

Comment: @sanosdole The version is at least 9.1 please.